# How do I get the list of files in a directory in a classpath that is included from a JAR?

Tags: java, classloader

How do I get the list of files in a directory in a classpath that is included from a JAR?

The question is not about opening a JAR file literally and finding files under a directory in it. The question is specifically how to list files in a directory that happened to be in a classpath because the JAR was included in the classpath. So there should be no opening JAR files involved. If this isn't possible please explain why and how it should be done without knowing the filename of the jar beforehand.

Say the project is dependent on another project whose resource structure is as the following:

```
src/main/resources/testFolder
 - fileA.txt
 - fileB.txt
```

Given that the testFolder being available in the classpath, how do I enumerate the files under it?

The testFolder ends up being inside the JAR which is inside the WAR's lib folder as where dependencies should be.

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether testFolder ends up in the JAR.

Comment: @pvg, yes of course. In fact, trying to call this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("testFolder") returns a URL instance (Enumerable<URL> with one element, which represents the testFolder itselt). Had it not been included, that code will not return a URL.

Comment: I don't think the classloader is really intended for that (and specifically, getResources is not). Your best bet is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Comment: @pvg, wouldn't that require you to know of the JAR's filename beforehand? Developers scanning the classpath directory shouldn't be concerned about the filename of the JAR because that can change, don't you think? And that info isn't just available. All they need to be concerned about is that there's such directory.

Comment: The classpath is available to you at runtime and for your typical classloader, contains the explicit names of the jar files. A classloader's job is to find named things not to serve as a directory of names. The assumption also is the resources you put in a JAR are static - you know what they are at build time.  Still, there isn't anything stopping you from rooting around a JAR file, it's just that the classloader isn't going to do it for you.

Comment: @pvg, I'm taking back my words. I guess you're right. There's no other way to actually do it without opening the JAR.

Comment: You can make this a little saner by making that a part of your build/deploy process. That way looking around for jars at runtime (which may not always be reliable, depending on how your project is deployed) is not an issue - you generate the names of the resources at build time and retrieve them with the classloader at runtime as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver scanner = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    Resource[] resources;
    try {
        resources = scanner.getResources("classpath*:testFolder/**/*.*");
        for (int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
            log.info("resource: {}", resources[i].getFilename() );
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Upon reading the underlying implementation, I found the following:

```
URLConnection con = rootDirResource.getURL().openConnection();
JarFile jarFile;
String jarFileUrl;
String rootEntryPath;
boolean newJarFile = false;

if (con instanceof JarURLConnection) {
    // Should usually be the case for traditional JAR files.
    JarURLConnection jarCon = (JarURLConnection) con;
    ResourceUtils.useCachesIfNecessary(jarCon);
    jarFile = jarCon.getJarFile();
    jarFileUrl = jarCon.getJarFileURL().toExternalForm();
    JarEntry jarEntry = jarCon.getJarEntry();
    rootEntryPath = (jarEntry != null ? jarEntry.getName() : "");
}
else {
    // No JarURLConnection -> need to resort to URL file parsing.
    // We'll assume URLs of the format "jar:path!/entry", with the protocol
    // being arbitrary as long as following the entry format.
    // We'll also handle paths with and without leading "file:" prefix.
    String urlFile = rootDirResource.getURL().getFile();
    int separatorIndex = urlFile.indexOf(ResourceUtils.JAR_URL_SEPARATOR);
    if (separatorIndex != -1) {
        jarFileUrl = urlFile.substring(0, separatorIndex);
        rootEntryPath = urlFile.substring(separatorIndex + ResourceUtils.JAR_URL_SEPARATOR.length());
        jarFile = getJarFile(jarFileUrl);
    }
    else {
        jarFile = new JarFile(urlFile);
        jarFileUrl = urlFile;
        rootEntryPath = "";
    }
    newJarFile = true;
}
```

Looking at Spring's implementation, it seems the only way to do it is to actually treat the resource as a JAR file.